# How can I modify or remove properties values? - Jena API

Tags: java, awt, rdf, jena, owl

I'm using Jena. I would like to know if there is a method that allows to modify or remove properties values of an instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Statements in Jena are, by design, immutable. To change the value of a property `p` of some subject `s`, you need to add a new statement with the same subject and predicate, and remove the old statement. This is always true in Jena, even if the API sometimes hides this from you. For example, `OntResource` and its subclasses have a variety of `setProperty` variants, but under the hood these are performing the same add-the-new-triple-and-delete-the-old process.

Answer (score 2):

It depends which Jena API you are using.  For instance, if you are using Jena 3.0 and the `Model` API, you can use [`Model.remove(Statement)`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#remove-org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Statement-) to remove a property by choosing the appropriate subject/predicate/object for the Statement.  Modification can be achieved by removing the old version of a Statement and adding the new version.

Comment: i got `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` , i use jena 3.1

Comment: Post a new Question, and include all relevant details including the full stacktrace, the Jena version, and relevant code from your application.

Answer (score 0):

To only remove the statement itself, i.e. the relation between the instance and the property value, you can use: 
[OntResource.removeProperty(Property, RDFNode)](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntResource.html#removeProperty%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode%29)

If you want to remove the property value altogether, i.e. the value and all relations to it, you can use: [OntResource.remove()](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntResource.html#remove%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar task: I need to delete the property with the  specified value. Hope the following code snippet will help someone.

```
  public void removeLabel(String language, String value) {
        NodeIterator nodeIterator = resource.getModel().listObjectsOfProperty(RDFS.label);
        RDFNode foundToDelete = null;
        while (nodeIterator.hasNext()) {
            RDFNode next = nodeIterator.next();
            boolean langsAreIdentical = next.asLiteral().getLanguage().equals(language);
            boolean valuesAreIdentical = next.asLiteral().getLexicalForm().equals(value);
            if (langsAreIdentical && valuesAreIdentical) {
                foundToDelete = next;
                break;
            }
        }
        resource.getModel().remove(resource, RDFS.label, foundToDelete);
    }
```